# url rewriting in asp.net 4.0 with two parameters

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, url-rewriting, url-routing

i had few dynamically generated urls like

```
http://localhost:35228/begineercontrols?name=untitled&id=2
http://localhost:35228/begineercontrols?name=linkbutton&id=34
http://localhost:35228/begineercontrols?name=lablebutton&id=5
```

and more, using routing I removed .aspx extension which is fine, now I want to make above urls more friendly like

```
http://localhost:35228/begineercontrols/untitled/2
```

how can i achive this for all dynamically generated urls please help me out
thanks in advace!

Answer (score 0):

In your App_Start/RouteConfig.cs, modify the code like this

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
        // Add Routes.
        RegisterCustomRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

   private static void RegisterCustomRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "begineercontrolsRoute",
            "begineercontrols/{name}/{id}",
            "~/begineercontrols.aspx"
        );
    }
```

Comment: what if I have to call only http://localhost:35228/begineercontrols  without any parameters, would it work with same rule define in route?